# 404 with youtube-mp3.org api

Tags: java, android, youtube, http-status-code-404, httprequest

I'm trying to make an app that can download mp3 files by a youtube url.

I did some research on the youtube-mp3.org api and this is the way I think it should be done:

1. Get `http://www.youtube-mp3.org/api/pushItem/?item=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xo9EV3A4oaA&xy=yx`
2. Step 1 returns an ID, which you have to use in the following request: `"http://www.youtube-mp3.org/api/itemInfo/?video_id=" + ID`
3. Step 2 returns another code, which you have to use in this request: `"http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?video_id=xo9EV3A4oaA&h=" + <code from step 2>`
4. Step 3 retruns the mp3.

Unfortunately, my code already fails at step 1: I'm getting a 404, page not found.

Here's my code (only for step 1):

```
private DefaultHttpClient createHttpClient() {
    HttpParams my_httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(my_httpParams, 3000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(my_httpParams, 15000);
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    ThreadSafeClientConnManager multiThreadedConnectionManager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(my_httpParams, registry);
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(multiThreadedConnectionManager, my_httpParams);
    return httpclient;
}

private class DownloadVid extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    int mStatusCode = 0;
    String content = "";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {

        String url = "http://www.youtube-mp3.org/api/pushItem/?item=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xo9EV3A4oaA&xy=yx";

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = createHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        httpget.addHeader("Accept-Location", "*");

        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            mStatusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

            if (mStatusCode == 200){
                content = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            mStatusCode = 0;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            mStatusCode = 0;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            mStatusCode = 0;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void arg) {

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Result=" + content + " StatusCode=" + mStatusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why it isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried these steps manually, with `curl` or `wget` or similar?

Comment: @MarkkuK. I don't know what that is. Could you explain?

Comment: You have to url-encode the item= argument.

Comment: @JasperKrijgsman How do you do that?

Comment: [curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) and [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) are command line tools for sending http requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the item parameter, like this:

```
String item = URLEncoder.encode("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xo9EV3A4oaA", "utf-8");
String url = "http://www.youtube-mp3.org/a/pushItem/?item="+item+"&xy=yx";
```

Or like this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
    .scheme("http")
    .authority("www.youtube-mp3.org")
    .path("/a/pushItem/")
    .appendQueryParameter("item", "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xo9EV3A4oaA")
    .appendQueryParameter("xy", "yx")
    .build();
```

Comment: Now I'm trying your second solution, but `new HttpGet(uri)`, gives me `HttpGet(Uri) is undefined`

Comment: I tried both this url: `http://www.youtube-mp3.org/api/pushItem/?item=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dxo9EV3A4oaA&xy=yx` and this url: `http://www.youtube-mp3.org/api/pushItem/?item=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xo9EV3A4oaA&xy=yx`. Both aren't working, not on android, nor in my desktop-browser.

Comment: That is really weird! replacing the api with a makes it work!

Comment: Where did you get the url from? This url comes from the form on the page.

Comment: Where's the form on the page?

Comment: I just got the url from different websites i found on google, but they're probably outdated.

Comment: how can you see the form? (I'm sorry, I'm a bit of a beginner)